# Reusing image-to-image GANs for spatial denoising of trajectories

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, conv-neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I work on particle tracking experiments that generate trajectories (x and y coordinates over time) from videos. Some experimental setups result in trajectories with a lot of spatial noise.

I'm looking into using machine-learning models to denoise those trajectories, as our available algorithmic methods are limited. My goal is to train the model with two inputs : simulated trajectories as ground truth, and the same trajectories with induced noise.

So far, most of the solutions I found regarding multiple inputs models that aren't classification or regression point to CNNs. However, I came across image-to-image denoising models (such as https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.07004) which seem to work based on the same relation between inputs, although with a different shape.

Could it be feasible to readapt such a model for this purpose ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: @desertnaut Could it be moved to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)  ?

Comment: *Maybe* it would be suitable for Data Science SE, but it could be closed there as well due to lack of details & clarity. I suggest you work more on it, delete this one, and post the improved version there.